# How do I split the following string?

Tags: python

I have the following string where I need to extract only the first digits from it.

```
string = '50.2000\xc2\xb0 E'
```

How do I extract 50.2000 from `string`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number can be followed by any kind of character, try using a regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> r = re.compile(r'(\d+\.\d+)')
>>> r.match('50.2000\xc2\xb0 E').group(1)
'50.2000'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mystring = '50.2000\xc2\xb0 E'
print mystring.split("\xc2", 1)[0]
```

**Output**

```
50.2000
```

Comment: Is it possible to split the string at the first \ ?

Comment: Thanks for the help people. Could you please tell me why its not splitting this string `u'26.2833\xb0 N'`? It says `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Ask a new question for that :)

Answer (score 1):

If you just wanted to split the first digits, just slice the string:

```
start = 10 #start at the 10th digit
print mystring[start:]
```

Demo:

```
>>> my_string = 'abcasdkljf23u109842398470ujw{}{\\][\\['
>>> start = 10
>>> print(my_string[start:])
23u109842398470ujw{}{\][\[
```

You can, split the string at the first `\`:

```
>>> s = r'50.2000\xc2\xb0 E'
>>> s.split('\\', 1)
['50.2000', 'xc2\\xb0 E']
```

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this using a regular expression:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: string = '50.2000\xc2\xb0 E'

In [3]: m = re.match('^([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)', string)

In [4]: m.group(0)
Out[4]: '50.2000'
```